# Where is the saved file is stored ? in Android

Tags: java, android

I used this code, but I can't find the saved file anywhere !

```
String filename = "fichier";
    String string = "bonjour";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
      outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you will not find this file unless you have rooted device(emulator is rooted) ... also define "anywhere" (where did you try to find it?)

Comment: all the files of my project, as well as files in my smartphone, I'm using a smartphone to test my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to find it if you open a new fileInputStream with the same parameters as your outputStream. You might also want to consider using SharedPreferences for something as simple as storing one String.

Comment: How can I do that ? please give more details

Comment: Not exactly sure why I am being downvoted for this, but anyways all the information you need is right here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: This is useful as you have described a way to read the file - though you haven't actually answered the actual question.

Comment: Well to answer your question you won't be able to find the data anywhere. The whole point of storing information internally is so other apps/ people cant get to it. If you want to be able to get the data off your phone you have to use external storage.

Comment: Still your answer is not to the point. The file will be created in /data/data/<packagename>/files.